# Won't Elena get old?

Tags: ending, the-vampire-diaries

In *The Vampire Diaries* S06E22 Elena is now human and has been linked with a spell to Bonnie's life; when Bonnie dies she will get her life back and wake up from this kind of "coma". I wonder, wouldn't she get old waiting for decades since she is now human?

Plus Nina Dobrev is out of the show so it doesn't make really sense that they added this condition for her death.

Answer (score 2):

No, she won't get old because as we know, she has been linked with Bonnie's life with a spell. So as Bonnie gets old, her life span will be credit in Elena's life span, i.e Bonnie's life will be debited and credit into Elena's life slowly-slowly.

Now, if Bonnie will die due to some accident or any reason, Elena will wake up, and then she will be using her life-span, so then she will get old. But until that, even though Elena is human now, she will not get old...